# Messages with level Diagnostic.Kind.NOTE (and others) on Annotation Processors

Tags: java, maven, annotation-processing

I have two Maven projects:

- The first defines an **annotation**, an **annotation processor** and a **provider-configuration file** to trigger the annotation processor through the ServiceLoader API.
- The other depends on the first and defines some **classes and interfaces**, and one of them is **annotated with the annotation defined in the first project**.

I invoke the build of the second project (after having built and installed the first) with `mvn clean && mvn compile`, just to be sure that compilation will happen and that annotation processing will run. It works as expected: the simple annontation processor just generates a resource file in the `target/classes/` directory containing some dummy data.

When I tried to output some information using `processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(...)` I started having some trouble. If I use `Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR`, the build stops and it prints the message, as I would expect. However, **with any other `Kind` (such as `NOTE` or `WARNING`), the message is not written on the screen**!

Some information on my environment:

```
Kubuntu 12.10
Linux 3.5.0-17-generic
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 06:44:56-0200)
Java version: 1.7.0_09, vendor: Oracle Corporation
```

I didn't explicitly declare the version of `maven-compiler-plugin` anywhere, so it must be using the default version (2.3.2? I'm not sure).

How does one enable the output of all the `Kind`s of messages on this setup? (ie, launching the annontation processor through maven)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, this is a bug in maven-compiler-plugin that has not been fixed: [MCOMPILER-66 - Compiler swallows messages from annotation processors](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOMPILER-66).

Answer (score 5):

Try to add following lines:

```
<configuration>
  <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
</configuration>
```

into the maven compiler-plugin definition in the pom.xml of the project. This solution works for me.

See:
https://gist.github.com/esamson/0777b97adde4c2f9bc31

Comment: I tried POM Property `<maven.compiler.showWarnings>true</maven.compiler.showWarnings>` and it also worked.